# Can we only change the font size for numeric values in a latex table

Tags: tables, fonts, fontsize

How can we change the font size of only numbers in a latex table?

mwe:

```
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
 \hline
 2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
 \hline
 3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
 \hline
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I know using `\tiny` or `\scriptsize` can make the table fonts smaller, but I want this only for the numbers.

Comment: What do you have in your real table, apart from  numbers and  column heads?

Answer (score 4):

You can check for an integer using `\IfInteger` and check for a decimal using `\IfDecimal`, both from the `xstring` package. The syntax for both commands is `\IfInteger{true code}{false code}`. Writing a new macro to do this is quite easy like this:

```
\newcommand*{\numfont}[2][\small]{%
    \IfInteger{#2}{{#1#2}}{%
    \IfDecimal{#2}{{#1#2}}{#2}%
    }%
}
```

This macro takes one optional argument and one mandatory argument, the optional one defaults to `\small`. Then, this new macro can be applied to table cells using the `collcell` package. For convenience, this is applied in a `newcolumntype`, named `C`, as below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring,array}
\usepackage{collcell}

\newcommand*{\numfont}[2][\small]{%
    \IfInteger{#2}{{#1#2}}{%
    \IfDecimal{#2}{{#1#2}}{#2}%
    }%
}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell{\numfont[\tiny]}}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{||CCCC||} 
 \hline
 Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
 \hline
 2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
 \hline
 3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
 \hline
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

> [image]